# Factorize use of repeated similar div blocks with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building an app with html/javascript.

I feel my code could be made cleaner and factorized with some javascript but don't know how to find this code (while keeping a very efficient page load performance).

```
<div id="deal-zone">
  <div class="deal">
    <span class="beamer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/></span>   
  </div>
  <div class="deal">
    <span class="beamer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></span>   
  </div>
  <div class="deal">
    <span class="beamer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></span>   
  </div>
  <div class="deal">
    <span class="beamer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></span>   
  </div>
  <div class="deal" >
    <span class="beamer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></span>   
  </div>
  <div class="deal" >
    <span class="beamer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></span>   
  </div>
  <div class="deal">
    <span class="beamer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></span>   
  </div>
  <div class="deal">
    <span class="beamer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></span>   
  </div>
  <div class="deal">
    <span class="beamer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></span>   
  </div>
  <div class="deal">
    <span class="beamer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></span>   
  </div>
</div>
```

As you see it's really very very repetitive as I have 10 times the exact same block.

What I am trying to do is simply something like this and i lack the javascript chops for it:

```
function(){display in the html make 10 times repeatedly 
<div class="deal">
        <span class="beamer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></span>   
      </div>
}
```

Note: if you wonder by the way, javascript is dynamically giving each  a certain position on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
      return Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min;
    }
    $(".deal").each(function () {
      var topPosition = getRandomInt(8, 70);  
      var leftPosition = getRandomInt(8, 92); 
      $(this).css({
        "top": topPosition+"%",
        "left": leftPosition+"%",
      });
    });

  });
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some tips that might you.

- If you want to use jQuery to generate the HTML for you, you can do the following:

  ```
  var numBlocks = 10;
  var $dealZone = $("#deal-zone");
  var $toAppend = $('<div class="deal"><span class="beamer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></span></div>');
  for(var c = 0; c < numBlocks; c++)
      $dealZone.append($toAppend.clone());
  ```

  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kt8uefe2/1/) to demonstrate (used `<li>`, sorry)

  However, I just want to point out, that is not a great SEO way to do things.  Dynamic HTML is not picked up so well by Search Engine crawlers, so it would look to the Search Engines that your content was missing.
- Your first `<span>` tag has a closing slash. This is not valid HTML.  Should be:

  ```
  data-target="#myModal">
  ```

  and not

  ```
  data-target="#myModal"/>
  ```
- It looks like your HTML is a list of some sort.  Semantically, you might want to consider using a list structure with `<ul>` and `<li>` tags.  You can still style these to remove the padding, margin, and bullets to display them any way you would like.
- To simplify CSS classes, (using your current HTML) you could remove the `class="deal"` and `class="beamer"` from every child element.  If you need this class for CSS styling, you can use the descendant selector (which targets all immediate children of the parent) as follows:

  ```
  #deal-zone > div { /*styles here*/ } /* targets the current "deal" class */
  #deal-zone > div > span { /*styles here*/ } /* targets the current ".beamer" class */
  ```
- You could also use the descendant selector in your jQuery function.  Use the following JavaScript to target the children without having the "deal" class:

  ```
  $("#deal-zone > div").each(function () { ... }
  ```
- In addition, you most likely don't need the repetitive `data-toggle` and `data-target` attributes on all of the children.  Since they are all the same, you can assign these attributes to the parent and access them with the following jQuery:

  ```
  var $dealZone = $('#deal-zone');
  var data-toggle = $dealZone.attr('data-toggle');
  var data-target = $dealZone.attr('data-target');
  ```
- In summary, here is a working example in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kt8uefe2/1/)

Comment: I edited my question to really show what I want to do. thanks for your reply, quite useful anyhow. Does your last bullet point enable me to do what I wanted (see edit) ? I'm trying not to have these in plain html , it's too long. I might have 125 div like this to repeat...

Comment: thanks a lot for the jsfiddle, what I'd like is not to have in the HMTL of your jsfiddle but generate 125 divs only by javascript instead of writing 125 divs...hope I get make my objective clearer :)

Comment: well these are great advice. but still, in your latest jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/kt8uefe2/) I still have to write all the 125   <li>
    <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Item 1</span>   
  </li>. What I want is to write it only once in javascript and ask it to duplicate the div 125 times/ so that my code is cleaner/shorter.

Comment: There, how's that.  Please see the note at the bottom of the first bullet concerning SEO as well.  Also please accept as answer if this helped you.